# How do I fix a null reference error on a dbcontext in vb?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, controls, dbcontext

My code builds and runs, but when I reference the dbcontext during runtime I get "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'". I use the context a lot other places in the solution and it works, but it is c# the other places. This is VB.

```
Imports DataServices
Imports Previdence.Domain.Model
Imports Previdence.Business.Model.Report

Namespace UserControls    
Partial Class RemissionControl
        Inherits UserControl
        Private previdenceContext As PrevidenceContext
        Private patient As Subject
        Private remissionButtonStatus As Boolean?
        Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

            Dim snapshotId As Guid = Utility.StringToGuid(Request.QueryString("snapshotId"))
            patient = (From su In previdenceContext.Subjects
                       Join ep In previdenceContext.Episodes On su.SubjectId Equals ep.SubjectId
                       Join sn In previdenceContext.Snapshots On ep.SubjectId Equals sn.SnapshotId
                       Where sn.SnapshotId = snapshotId
                       Select su).FirstOrDefault()
            remissionButtonStatus = patient.RemissionButtonOn
            If remissionButtonStatus = True Then
                remissionRButtonYes.Checked = True
                remissionRButtonNo.Checked = False
            Else
                remissionRButtonYes.Checked = False
                remissionRButtonNo.Checked = True
            End If
        End Sub

        'TODO: getting null reference error on the dbcontext
        Private Sub remissionRButtonYes_click() Handles remissionRButtonYes.CheckedChanged
            If remissionRButtonYes.Checked = True Then
                patient.RemissionButtonOn = True
            Else patient.RemissionButtonOn = False
            End If
            previdenceContext.SaveChanges()
        End Sub

        Private Sub remissionRButtonNo_click() Handles remissionRButtonNo.CheckedChanged
            If remissionRButtonNo.Checked = True Then
                patient.RemissionButtonOn = False
            Else patient.RemissionButtonOn = True
            End If
            previdenceContext.SaveChanges()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Which line does the error happen on? Note that `.FirstOrDefault()` can return `Nothing`.

Comment: Where is the `previdenceContext` created?

Comment: @Andrew Morton: the error occurs on the line "patient = (From su In previdenceContext.Subjects"

Comment: @RobertBaron: I believe it is created when instantiated on line "Private previdenceContext As PrevidenceContext". Is this the correct instantiation of an object in VB?

Comment: The line you mentioned only declares the variable. You need to create an instance with New.

Comment: This is one reason why a context variable should not be declared at class level.  It should always be declared and created as close to its use as possible and then disposed of as soon as possible after that.

Comment: @RobertBaron: This was my issue. Adding "New" as you suggested fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the kind of error that gets caught by IntelliSense.

Anyway, you will avoid the error if you replace the declaration:
`Private previdenceContext As PrevidenceContext` with `Private previdenceContext As New PrevidenceContext`, however you code will still not work, because `previdenceContext` has no data.

You are probably missing a line of code to populate `previdenceContext`.

Comment: Adding "New" as you suggested fixed the problem.

Comment: @Unconquered - However, simply adding `New` creates a new problem, a memory leak. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use the `previdenceContext` in several members of your class, you can declared it at class level, and instantiate it in the `Sub New()`. The context must be disposed of, so your class needs to implements `IDisposable` and dispose of `previdenceContext`.

```
Partial Class RemissionControl
    Implements IDisposable
    Inherits UserControl

    Private previdenceContext As PrevidenceContext

    Sub New()
        ' This is the parameterless constructor. If you have a constructor with
        ' parameter such as passing the connection string name, use it. Do what you
        ' you do in your C# code.
        previdenceContext New PrevidenceContext()
    End Sub

    ' Your class implementation ...

#Region "IDisposable Support"
    Private disposedValue As Boolean ' To detect redundant calls

    ' IDisposable
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                ' TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
                If previdenceContext IsNot Nothing Then previdenceContext.Dispose()
            End If

            ' TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override Finalize() below.
            ' TODO: set large fields to null.
        End If
        disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    ' TODO: override Finalize() only if Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    'Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    '    ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above.
    '    Dispose(False)
    '    MyBase.Finalize()
    'End Sub

    ' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above.
        Dispose(True)
        ' TODO: uncomment the following line if Finalize() is overridden above.
        ' GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```